# Error while updating mongo db object by id

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to update my mongodb database by Id but I am getting error `userId.save` is not a function. What I did was get all the databases data by `Object.findById` then used `Object.assign` to assign an updated value to the specified key then saved the updated Object back to the database. Where did I go wrong. How can I update a mongodb object by Id. Thanks in advance.

```js
const Users = require('pathToSchema')

const userId = Users.findById('ObjectId')
Object.assign(userId, '{"email": "test@gmail.com"}')
//error arrises here. "userId.save is not a function"
userId.save()
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  })
```

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const users_Schema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
}, {timestamps: true})

const Users = mongoose.model('users', users_Schema)
module.exports = Users;
```

Comment: have you tried `Object.assign(userId, {"email": "test@gmail.com"})` without quotes for the second `{"email": "test@gmail.com"}` object?

Comment: @CarloMoretti yeah i get same error

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning the `email` prop instead of using `Object.assign`. Also bear in mind that you need to assign 2 objects but you assign a string instead.
Try this:

```js
const userId = await Users.findById('ObjectId')
userId.email = 'test@gmail.com';
userId.save()
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  })
```

Also, make sure you create a model from the schema and use it to `findById`. For instance:

```js
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name:String,
    username:{type:String, required:true, index:{unique:true}},
    password:{type:String, required:true, select:false}
});

const UserModel = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

const user = await UserModel.findById(...);
user.save();
```

Comment: I still get same error

Comment: @seriously I have updated my answer. Please make sure you have your model and schema properly specified.

Comment: I already do all your updated code in my schema page and import it using ```const Users = require('pathToSchema')```. Also your schema doesn't even have an email attribute.

Comment: My `schema` and `model` was just for reference and it does not exactly represent your format. Could you please share your code with `schema` and `model`?

Comment: I have uploaded my schema page above.

Comment: I have posted a working solution below. Can you please check it and tell me if it has any flaws. Thanks!

Comment: It will work but I advise you use `await` instead of `.then().catch()`. I will make your code more readable

Answer (score 0):

The `findById` is not execute yet. You have to use it with a `callback` or an `exec()`. You can learn more at [mogoose doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#executing).
Try change line `const userId = Users.findById('ObjectId')` to `const userId = await Users.findById('ObjectId').exec()`. `exec()` will return a promise, so you could use `await` to get result.
Furthermore, the `Object.assign` statement is not correct, there is no need for the string character (which is '). It's just `Object.assign(userId, {"email": "test@gmail.com"})`

Comment: I get error when i use ```await``` because its not wrapped by an async function

Comment: you could use an `callback` function instead. Try this one ```let userId; Users.findById('ObjectId', function (err, u) {userId = u}); ```

Comment: It's also better if you check for the error before the assignment. something like `if (err) {console.log(err); return;}` before the `userId = u` assignment

Comment: Doesn't work. I get error ```Cannot convert undefined or null to object``` on Object.assign

Comment: I have posted a working solution below. Can you please check it and tell me if it has any flaws. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```js
Users.findById('ObjectId')
  .then((result) => {
    Object.assign(result, {
      "email": "test@gmail.com"
    })
    result.save()
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  })
```

Comment: It's good to go :). The problem in the question is `Users.findById` is an asynchronous function, and this code is handled it.